# Back scanner reading after user error - java

Tags: java

I have read user input that must be only of type int, the problem comes when the user enters letter instead of a int. I know how to handle the exception, but I would like to return the scanner read where the user has made a mistake. How can I do? 
I already tried with an infinite loop, but it does not work.

```
try{
    System.out.print("enter number: ");
    value = scanner.nextInt();
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.err.println("enter a number!");
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your attempt with the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While other answers give you correct idea to use loop you should avoid using exceptions as part of your basic logic. Instead you can use `hasNextInt` from `Scanner` to check if user passed integer.

```
System.out.print("enter number: ");
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    scanner.nextLine();// consume incorrect values from entire line
    //or 
    //tastiera.next(); //consume only one invalid token
    System.out.print("enter number!: ");
}
// here we are sure that user passed integer
int value = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

A loop is the right idea. You just need to mark a success and carry on:

```
boolean inputOK = false;
while (!inputOK) {
    try{
        System.out.print("enter number: ");

        numAb = tastiera.nextInt();

        // we only reach this line if an exception was NOT thrown
        inputOK = true;
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        // If tastiera.nextInt() throws an exception, we need to clean the buffer
        tastiera.nextLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should add `tastiera.nextLine();` in the catch block. Because when `Scanner` throw an exception, it does not read anything. So if user input an invalid line, your loop will never end